# International student loans in the US

Tags: education

I'm weighing all my options before the fall application and I wanted to know if it is possible to take out loans in the US as an international master's degree student.

Any tips where to look?
Best I've seen are private loans with an American cosignatory. Is it really the extent of loan options for an international? Do universities extend loans to their students or help in getting private loans?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Yes check with your universities Student Services Department. Most of the universities also give you scholarships provided you have some good scores in GRE/TOEFL or whatever they require. Banks also give Student loans to International students provided you have a credit-worthy US-Citizen as a Co-signer.
But most of the international students are eligible for scholarships.
Good luck.

http://www.edupass.org/finaid/loans.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Try to check (email) with the offices for international students and scholar that in some universities also handle financial issues for foreign students. They will give you the best options. If you're willing to do research or teaching work, I'd suggest you to personally contact Faculties or graduate program secretaries that may have such options for you. In some universities, most national and international grad students are under teaching or research assistantships, have tuition waived and monthly stipend, and this also build up their cv. This may not apply to specific degrees such as MBA, but if you're in science, technology, education or engineer, it is likely that you can find assistantship to support you.
It may be too late to find an assistantship for the fall semester, you can consider to start next spring as well.
good luck!